# How to get form input array into PHP array but not empty field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form like the one below which is posted to same page, and the user can dynamically add more textbox with jquery.

```
        <h1> Add Your Order </h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span> Click to Add </span></a></p>
        <div id="container">
        <input type="text" class="pid" id="' + counter + '" name="Product[]"  />
        <input type="text" class="qid" id="' + counter + '" name="Quantity[]" /><br />
        </div><br />
        <input type= "submit" Name="submit_order" value="Submit"> 
    </form>
```

everything work fine but if someone add more textbox and leave some textbox as empty then it going to submit. this is my problem i don't want to submit empty textboxes in my table and i want  server side solution for this.

**Here is my full code with php**

```
<body>
    <?php
    if ( isset($_POST['submit_order']) ) {
        if ( !empty($_POST['Product'])  && !empty($_POST['Quantity']) ) {
            $product = ($_POST['Product']);
            $quantity = ($_POST['Quantity']);
            foreach ($product as $id => $value) {
            $products = ($product[$id]);
            $quantitys = ($quantity[$id]);
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT iNTO myorders (product,quantity) VALUES ('$products','$quantitys')", $connection);
            }
        }
    echo "<i><h2><stront>" . count($_POST['Product']) . "</strong> Entry Added </h2></i>";
    mysql_close();
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_POST['submit_order'])) { 
    ?>
    <h1> Add Your Order </h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span> Click to Add </span></a></p>
            <div id="container">
            <input type="text" class="pid" id="' + counter + '" name="Product[]"  />
            <input type="text" class="qid" id="' + counter + '" name="Quantity[]" /><br />
            </div><br />
        <input type= "submit" Name="submit_order" value="Submit"> 
    </form>
    <?php } 
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you just ignore the empty ones and process the rest?

Comment: i use !empty() function and process rest but every filed submit in my table .

Comment: If you want to prevent it from submitting you have to do it client-side. PHP can't prevent it from subnmitting. You can put `required` in the `<input>` elements, and modern browsers won't allow them to be submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
foreach ($_POST[Product] as $key => $value):
    if (empty($value)):
        unset($_POST[Product][$key]);
    endif;
endforeach;

foreach ($_POST[Quantity] as $key => $value):
    if (empty($value)):
        unset($_POST[Quantity][$key]);
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter` to get the elements of the arrays that are not empty. If the number of non-empty elements is different from the original array sizes, the user left some fields blank.

```
$filled_product = array_filter($product);
$filled_quantity = array_filter($quantity);
if (count($filled_product) < count($product) || count($filled_quantity) < count($quantity)) {
    // Report error because of unfilled fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping me, unfortunately no one give me a complete solution for this question
but @Wranorn give me a idea and i change my code and yes this solve my question

**here is my solution for this**

```
    <body>
    <?php
    if ( isset($_POST['submit_order']) ) {

        $product = ($_POST['Product']);
        $quantity = ($_POST['Quantity']);

        foreach ($product as $id => $value) {
            $products = ($product[$id]);
            $quantitys = ($quantity[$id]);

            if (!empty($products) && !empty($quantitys)) {
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT iNTO myorders (product,quantity) VALUES ('$products','$quantitys')", $connection);
            }
        }
    echo "<i><h2><stront>" . count($_POST['Product']) . "</strong> Entry Added </h2></i>";
    mysql_close();
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_POST['submit_order'])) { 
    ?>
    <h1> Add Your Order </h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span> Click to Add </span></a></p>
            <div id="container">
            <input type="text" class="pid" id="' + counter + '" name="Product[]"  />
            <input type="text" class="qid" id="' + counter + '" name="Quantity[]" /><br />
            </div><br />
        <input type= "submit" Name="submit_order" value="Submit"> 
    </form>
    <?php } 
    ?>
</body>
```